# Horizontal scroll bar won't go away?

Tags: css

Having trouble with a horizontal scroll bar that pops up.

My page is set up like so:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<article>
</article>

</body>
</html>
```

My css

```
article {
    width:100%;
    margin:0px auto;
    padding:25px;
}
```

I'm also using [Yahoo's Reset CSS](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/). The trouble is the 100% on Article is giving me a horizontal scroll that I can't get rid of. I want it to stretch the length of the window with just a bit of space on the right and left.

Comment: It looks like the article is wider than a parent element. Try setting the body to 100% width and see if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `width` property sets the width of the content, excluding padding, so the total width required by the element is all of the available width plus 2 times 25px.

Omit `width: 100%` (so that the default `width: auto` will be used).

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me, I was having the same problem only in Firefox

```
body {
     overflow-y: auto;
     overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I don't believe you can actually set one to auto and the other to hidden, per https://stackoverflow.com/a/6433475/1449525

Answer (score 0):

100% Width + 25px padding = container.width+25px. Just add `article { overflow-x:hidden }` and it should hide it.

Comment: @JustinM Im not getting a scrollbar on your fiddle, recheck?

Comment: Might only be happening in Chrome. What broswer are you using?